# Holography, what is difference in it and photography in detail and in concern with physical meaning?

Tags: optics, hologram

I don't understand what new will we get by it, mean I know it will get phase difference and features like that but physically what will we get? And it's reconstruction of image method?

Answer (score 1):

A holographic record contains more information than a regular photograph; an ordinary photograph records the intensity of light projected upon the recording surface: a flat image, very similar to how the human eye perceives the world.

With a holographic recording the phase information is encoded in the media; when the holographic image is reconstructed this phase information supports the creation of a 3D image; you can actually walk around some images, and study the details from differing directions.

The usual technique is to start with a laser beam and split it into two parts; the first beam illuminates the object directly, while the second beam serves as a reference, and by means of optical interference between the light coming from the illuminated object and that of the direct reference beam, the holographic image is encoded into the recording media.

Image reconstruction requires a similar split laser beam, presented at the correct angles and of the same wavelength.  It is also possible to make white light holograms, and to use other coherent light sources; I once made a white light hologram of a colorful holiday decoration using fluorescent lighting; you could see the image fairly well when the glass plate was lit by fluorescent lighting.

For more details see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holography